# Custom Input Form (Sharepoint)

Tags: sharepoint

I'd like to create a custom input form that collects employees hours. This data will be saved to a Access Web Datasheet in Sharepoint. How do I go about doing this? I have Sharepoint Designer and I've created a basic input form but need to link it to datasheet on Sharepoint. Any help is appreciated as this is my first attempt at SP development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found the solution on my own after experimenting with Sharepoint Designer and found I don't even have to build a form, it does it for you! Open your Data Source Details window and point to the Sharepoint List you're keying off of. Select the fields you want in your form and there's a drop down that says 'Insert Selected Fields  as...' and choose New Input option. This will build a form that submits directly to your Sharepoint list! Now to pretty it up and create some KPI's off the list...